# mongoose $elemMatch returns all results instead only the first

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As I understand $elemMatch should find and return only the first elem` it encounters
but instead it returns all the array, this is the DB data

```
{
    _id:  "123123123",
    "user_id": "0",
    "list": [
     {
        "employee_code": 1111,
        "list": []
     }, 
     {
        "employee_code": 2222,
        "list": []
     }
    ]
}
```

I want to return only the first elem'

this is my query:

```
Reports.find(
 {user_id:"123123123"},
 {"list":{$elemMatch:{"employee_code": 1111}}
})
```

I expect it to return  only the first obj' `list:[{employee_code:1111,...}]`
but instead it returns all the array

better ex:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `$filter` in aggregration

```
db.collection.aggregrate([
[
  {
    '$project': {
      'list': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$list', 
          'as': 'list1', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$list1.employee_code', 1111
            ]
          }
        }
      }, 
      'user_id': 1
    }
  }
]
])
```

Comment: I have a workaround but my question is why elemMatch doesnt work as expected

Comment: elemMatch work as expected and find doc that element of array with specific condition

Comment: elemMatch should only return the first Item and not both the second doesnt even match the condition

Comment: The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 1):

`$elemMatch` will return document that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria. You should use positional operator `$` instead:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": "123123123",
  "list.employee_code": 1111
},
{
  "list.$": 1
});
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gQvKniEVgfT

Comment: It doesnt work and what you say about $elemMatch is what I asked that it doesnt work as expected